# Creating JSON from list of tuples

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a list of tuples in the form of:

```
result=[(0,"string1",4,"string2"),(1,"string3",10,"string4")]
```

I want it in JSON format of:

```
one={"id":0,
      "firstname":"string1",
       "age":4}
```

for each tuple in the list by defining key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the json library,

```py
somedict = { "id"     : [ x[0] for x in data ],
            "name" : [ x[1] for x in data ],
            "age" : [ x[2] for x in data ],
           }
```

```py
print(json.dumps(somedict))
```